# Prove that in compact sets, a twice continuously differentiable function satisfies a certain property.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, compactness

Ok, here it goes the problem:

Let $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a function that belongs to $C^2(U)$ (i.e. the second partial derivatives of $f$ are continuous), where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n.$ How can I prove that for every  $K\subset U$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n,$ there is a constant $C_K>0$ such that
\begin{equation}
|f(x+h)-f(x)-h\cdot\nabla f(x)|\leq C_K|h|^2
\end{equation}
for every $x\in K$ and $|h|\leq1?$

Comment: Make a question out of the post, add what you have tried.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: Think about and try a basic theorem that is likely to be relevant.

Comment: I think $h\leq 1$ is wrong, you can go outside of $U$ if $K$ is not small enough.